# Check a random location in a list by using a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make the computer guess a random character on this Board (which just consists of a long list of characters) and then check if that random character is either C,D,S or B string.

```
from random import randint
Index=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
Row1=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
Row2=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
Row3=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
Row4=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
Row5=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
Row6=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
Row7=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
Row8=["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]
Board=[Row1,Row2,Row3,Row4,Row5,Row6,Row7,Row8]
RanRow=randint(1,8)
RanIndex=randint(0,7)
RanRow=RanRow-1
CompGuess=[RanRow,RanIndex]
if Board[CompGuess] ==("C") or Board[CompGuess] ==("D") or Board[CompGuess] ==("S") or Board[CompGuess] ==("B"):
#Do something
else:
#Do something
```

When I attempt to check the character stored in the location chosen randomly by the computer in the line:

```
    if Board[CompGuess] ==("C") or Board[CompGuess] ==("D") or Board[CompGuess] ==("S") or Board[CompGuess] ==("B"):
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

I believe the Python does not like having lists as indexes, however I may be mistaken.

Comment: You can't pass lists as indexers to lists.

Comment: You have to use Board[RanRow][RanIndex]

Comment: `Board[RanRow][RanIndex] == "C"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a list of integers as the index to your board. When you are looking for your random position, try using `Board[RanRow][RanIndex]`.

Answer (score 1):

Take your optimized code:

```
from random import randint

Index=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
Board=[["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",],
["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",],
["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",],
["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",],
["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",],
["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",],
["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",],
["Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z","Z",]]
RanRow=randint(0, 7)
RanIndex=randint(0, 7)
CompGuess = Board[RanRow][RanIndex]

if CompGuess in ["C" , "D", "S", "B"]:
#Do something
else:
#Do something
```

Answer (score -1):

Python doesn't allows to pass list as list indexers.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Especially since the [already accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47909520/501011) gives better explanation.